# C code to Read data from nonin Pulse Oximeter device via bluetooth Serial Port profile in linux

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth, spp

I am trying to communicate to the Nonin Pulse oximeter device to read the data (Pulse rate and SPO2 level) via Bluetooth. Nonin device supports SPP and HDP profile. I want to communicate through SPP profile. I am able to scan and pair with the device by the sample code available in Bluez. 
    Please tell me next steps how to send command and read data from the device. I have got struck at this point.

Comment: Are you a registered OEM or partner with Nonin? That is, have you signed their NDA or received permission for you to access their technical specification? Unless you have I can not share with you the exact steps to read and interpret their data.

Comment: Nonin PO device data sheet is available in net. we have purchased the PO device. what commands to send and how to parse the received data is given in the data sheet itself. But I just wanted to know the How can I implement it in C code.

Comment: Since you say you know the commands to send then your question is really how to read/write gatt characteristics. Please have a look at this thread which discusses that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720452/dbus-apis-in-bluez

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a late response, but I recently setup data acquisition from a Nonin PalmSAT 2500A VET unit. I am using the RTC-1000 cable and an RS232 to USB converter.

This is straight from the manual:

"Information from the device, in the real-time mode, is sent in an ASCII serial format at 9600 baud with 9 data bits, 1 start bit, and 1 stop bit. The data are output at a rate of once per second.

NOTE: The 9th data bit is used for odd parity in memory playback mode. In real-time mode, it is always set to the mark condition. Therefore the real-time data may be read as 8 data bits, no parity.

Real-time data may be printed or displayed by devices other than the pulse oximeter. On power up a header is sent identifying the format and the time and date. Thereafter, the data are sent once per second in the following format:

```
SPO2=XXX HR=YYY
```

where “XXX” represents the SpO2 value, and “YYY” represents the pulse rate. The SpO2 and pulse rate will be displayed as “---” if there are no data available for the data reading."

Link to manual:
http://www.proactmedical.co.uk/proshop_support_docs/2500aman.pdf

What model oximeter are you working with?